# Trouble disabling react-hooks/exhaustive-deps warning when using redux action creator inside useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, eslint

Trying to call a redux action creator inside a useEffect hook the following warning-

```
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getPlanQuotes'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

This is the useEffect hook-

```
const { getPlanQuotes } = props;

useEffect(() => {
   getPlanQuotes();
}, []);
```

So I tried disabling it using `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`. Like this-

```
useEffect(() => {
    getPlanQuotes();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, []);
```

But it still throws the warning on the console without the `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` being specified

And also the editor throws the following error-
[image]

.eslintrc config-

```
{
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended", "prettier"],
    "env": {
        "jest": true,
        "browser": true,
        "node": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "plugins": ["json", "prettier"],
    "rules": {
        "prettier/prettier": ["error"],
        "no-console": "off"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "rules": {
            "no-underscore-dangle": [
                "error",
                {
                    "allow": ["_id", "b_codes_id"]
                }
            ],
            "react/prop-types": [1]
        },
        "settings": {
            "import/resolver": "meteor"
        },
        "globals": {
            "_": true,
            "CSSModule": true,
            "Streamy": true,
            "ReactClass": true,
            "SyntheticKeyboardEvent": true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post actual code snippets and not screen grabs. Can't see any of your hook code in that image.

Comment: @DrewReese, sorry about that and for the delay. I've added the actual code snippets. Please check them.

Comment: Do you mind sharing your lint config? (.eslintrc.json or .eslintrc.config, etc..) You may be missing the rule definition there. Interesting that the linter is still flagging the hook though, but lets check anyway. It should be in your project root.

Comment: I don't recommend you ignore the linter's directions. Why don't you add `getPlanQuotes` to the dependency?

Comment: @SILENT sometimes it is ok to ignore though, for example, when you want an effect to trigger only once, when mounted, by using an empty dependency array, or other times when the variable is a callback (like the OP's snippet) that you know won't change/mutate during the life of the component, so you don't include it in the array. The downside, however, is if whenever updating the hook without reconsidering the dependencies leading to logical bugs.

Comment: @DrewReese React hook developers considered those situations when writing the eslint config. In fact, regardless of the annoying errors that pop up, I've found it to solve more problems than it creates. In this case, if `getPlanQuotes` doesn't change but a new function reference is generated on each refresh, then `getPlanQuotes` should be encapsulated with `useCallback`.

Comment: @SILENT Yes, I'm aware, but it isn't 100% foolproof. I agree, and generally let the linter automagically fix my dependency arrays, or follow the suggestions. But as I stated though, *sometimes* you as the developer *do* know better. The case I laid out about the "on mount" triggering is (at least in the version I use) always flagged.

Comment: @DrewReese I also thought that before I asked on Github. Dan Abramov corrected me. For mounting, especially state, `useState(() => { ... call function and return state }` . For functions, `useEffect`

Comment: @DrewReese, @SILENT I've added the `.eslintrc` config. And yes logically `getPlanQuotes` doesn't have to be in the dependency array as it is an action creator that has been defined in another file. That's the reason why I'm trying to ignore the linter's warning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was a problem with the `.eslintrc` configuration as @DrewReese suspected. The `plugins` array was missing `react-hooks` and the `rules` object was missing `react-hooks` rules.

So, the final configuration is as follows-

```
{
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended", "prettier"],
    "env": {
        "jest": true,
        "browser": true,
        "node": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "plugins": ["json", "prettier", "react-hooks"], //added "react-hooks" here
    "rules": {
        "prettier/prettier": ["error"],
        "no-console": "off"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "rules": {
            "no-underscore-dangle": [
                "error",
                {
                    "allow": ["_id", "b_codes_id"]
                }
            ],
            "react/prop-types": [1],
            "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error", // added "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks"
            "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn" // added "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps"
        },
        "settings": {
            "import/resolver": "meteor"
        },
        "globals": {
            "_": true,
            "CSSModule": true,
            "Streamy": true,
            "ReactClass": true,
            "SyntheticKeyboardEvent": true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But .eslintrc file is only while coding, what about warning for the built project?

Comment: @pmiranda could you elaborate? What do you mean by built project?